# Can run Javascript but not jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm running into a strange problem - I tried running a basic function in JS and jQuery, and while the former worked, the latter didn't.

**JS - okay**

```
alert('Works');
```

**jQuery - not okay**

```
$(document).ready({
    alert('Works');
});
```

Here's some facts:

1. My references to the jQuery library are correct

   (And pretty sure my Internet connection is steady :)
2. I'm using a CDN - CloudFlare to be exact, but I've switched development mode on and Rocket Loader off - so all the code I've uploaded to the server is WYSIWYG (CloudFlare adds some stuff in the  tags if you leave Rocket Loader on.
3. I tried running the alert code in the head section, and elsewhere in the body tags, to no avail.

What could have possibly gone wrong?

**EDIT 1**: The page is here - http://casestudieslounge.com/chat/BIM/WebContent/chat.php

Comment: Are you getting any errors in your console ?

Comment: If you state your references are okay, and the rest of the code is okay, why don't you give the entire source so we can check it.

Comment: check your browser console - it could be that you have placed your script before jQuery include script or there is a `jQuery.noConflict()` in your code

Comment: @rorofromfrance actually, I just checked...yes - it says unexpected token. I've updated the question with a link to my page. Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your `$(document).ready` is a syntax error because you're passing an object literal containing  the alert, which isn't valid JavaScript. Pass a function instead:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    alert('works');
});
```

Comment: Oh dear...I can't believe I made such a beginner's mistake. Thanks for catching this :)

Comment: Anybody else reckon this kind of mistake is something of a rite of passage to all developers using jQuery?

Comment: My word, in spite of being above average in jQuery I couldn't spot the syntactical error. Nice eye

Answer (score 0):

You just need to call the function after .ready(

like this: 
    $(document).ready(function() {
           alert('works');
});